# Air conditioner

Tags: electrical

I have a 2012 Ford Fusion. I just got my a/c recharge.  The mechanic thought it was the compressor, but he put on a new fuse and it started to blow right out. But now, it blows out cold in one vent, and lukewarm in the middle vent.I just got my airbags replace at the dealership,  and after that, my car seems to start acting up. Do you suggest that I change the rest of my fuses, or could you help me with this problem?

Comment: They may have upset something doing the airbags but it may depend which ones...

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If you have dual zone HVAC in your Fusion, it could be the blend door actuator for the middle vent has gone afoul.